# iPhone's Do not disturb, exception for Slack notifications and except for some calls

Tags: iphone, notifications, call, do-not-disturb, slack

I want to silence my iPhone during certain hours of the day manually …
but with two exceptions:

- Some of my contacts are important and I want to receive calls from them (I know how to do it).
- I have a very important Slack channel which I do not want to be silent at any time.

How can I achieve this?

**Update :** If there is a 3rd party application to do this i hope someone suggest it ..

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have DND exceptions for apps.  Are you interested in 3rd party apps for the solution?

Comment: If 3rd party apps can do something like this then Sure .. @fsb

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Comment: What program does Slack notification not silent when iPhone is in DND ? thanks. @fsb